# How can I set a pre-build event in an ASP.Net MVC 2 Application in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, pre-build-event

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 2 Application in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

I was researching about using the build configuration to copy the right web.config file for development and testing environment and found [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx). But, I am not able to find out how to set the pre-build event for my project, which is required according to the article.

How can I set the pre-build event?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pre-build events, you could try with [Web.Config Transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx).

**Edit:**

Step 5 of the article you linked explains how to do that, except that `call` command is missing, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472550/multiple-pre-build-events-in-visual-studio).

For more info on pre-build events see this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx).

Comment: +1 for solving my root problem. Now, I'd like to know about the pre-build events for MVC projects. Any idea how to do it :)