# Is it possible to call multiple post-build events in Delphi 2007?

Tags: delphi, build, delphi-2007, build-events

I am trying to run two cmd files from the post-build event of a Delphi 2007 project.

The build events are configured like this:

```
..\..\buildtools\postbuild.cmd $(OUTPUTDIR)$(OUTPUTNAME)
..\copydlls.cmd $(OUTPUTDIR)
```

The first one works fine, the second one seems to never get called at all.

If I change the order like this:

```
..\copydlls.cmd $(OUTPUTDIR)
..\..\buildtools\postbuild.cmd $(OUTPUTDIR)$(OUTPUTNAME)
```

Again, only the first one is executed.

Is this a known limitation / bug of Delphi 2007 or am I doing something wrong here?
(I could have sworn that this used to work in the past.)

EDIT: I found a workaround:

```
%comspec% /c ..\..\buildtools\postbuild.cmd $(OUTPUTDIR)$(OUTPUTNAME)
%comspec% /c ..\copydlls.cmd $(OUTPUTDIR)
```

This works as expected. Still odd.

EDIT2: There is another option, I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472841/49925) answer on StackOverflow:

```
call ..\..\buildtools\postbuild.cmd $(OUTPUTDIR)$(OUTPUTNAME)
call ..\copydlls.cmd $(OUTPUTDIR)
```

I guess (without having tried it), that is is a problem only if the build event is a cmd file and the past experience I cited above did not call cmd files but executables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the workaround I added in EDIT2 is the one that should be used, so I am adding this as an answer myself:

When calling cmd files (probably also bat files) a "call" must be added in front of it:

```
call ..\..\buildtools\postbuild.cmd $(OUTPUTDIR)$(OUTPUTNAME)
call ..\copydlls.cmd $(OUTPUTDIR)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face can be understood from the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490873.aspx) for the `call` command.

> **Call**
>
> Calls one batch program from another without stopping the parent batch
>   program.

In other words, if you omit `call` when executing a sub-program, then the parent batch program is stopped when the sub-program returns.

So, you must use `call` to execute sub-programs in your build actions.

**Update**

I did not mention this first time round, but implicit in the above is that the build actions are executed by the command interpreter, cmd.exe.

Comment: Which implies that the build events are executed as a batch program. Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is documented. I know that it is so having watched cmd.exe processes flicker into life as sub-processes of bds.exe in the process explorer tree view. But I cannot find docs that state that. Anyway, it's a good point that you make and I took it for granted in my answer. I've remedied that now.