# Precompiled headers question

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pdb-files, precompiled-headers

I am right now reorganizing my project and what recently was a simple application now became a pair of C++ projects - *static library* and *real application*.

I would like to share one precompiled header between two projects, but face some troubles with setting up the `.pdb` file paths.

Assume my first project is called `Library` and builds it's `.lib` file with a corresponding `Library.pdb` file. Now, the second project is called `Application` and builds everything into the same folder (`.exe` and **another** `Application.pdb` file).

Right now my both projects create their own precompiled headers file (`Library.pch` and `Application.pch`) based on **one** actual header file. *It works, but I think it's a waste of time and I also think there should be a way to share one precompiled header between two projects.*

If in my `Application` project I try to set the `Use Precompiled Header (/Yu)` option and set it to `Library.pch`, it wouldn't work, because of the following error:

```
error C2858: command-line option 'program database name "Application.pdb" inconsistent with precompiled header, which used "Library.pdb".
```

*So, does anyone know some trick or way to share **one** precompiled header between two projects preserving proper debug information?*

Comment: Add your vote: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98645/visual-c-build-c2859-on-rebuild-on-solution-with-shared-precompiled-headers?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645747/sharing-precompiled-headers-between-projects-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is, why do you want to share the precompiled header (PCH) files. Generally I woul d say, that does not make sense. PCH are used to speed up compiling not to share any information between different projects.

Since you also write about the PDB file, you probably want to debug the library code with your applications. This can be achieved by setting the /Fd parameter when compiling the library. When you link the library in your application and the linker finds the corresponding PDB file, you get full debug support.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds complicated and cumbersome to set up. More than that, it may not be possible at all.

Instead, you can include the precompiled header from one application into the second. It will still be compiled once for the second project, but maintenance becomes easy and you do not have to redefine the dependencies in the second project (just include them).