# using precompiled header from different project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers

I have two projects in Visual Studio 2010 that I want to share the precompiled header outputs .pch(i) file: one builds it and the other should only use it.

After Clean, and Rebuild Project1, the .pchi file is created.

Rebuild Project2 does a strange thing, it Deletes the .pchi file and then complains that can't find it for compilation.

What should I change to stop this behaviour (possibly in the file "Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Intel C++ Compiler XE 12.0.targets"?) ?

I've set the file to read-only, then of course Project2 Build complains:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\Intel
>   C++ Compiler XE 12.1\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Intel C++ Compiler XE
>   12.1.targets(84,5): error MSB3061: Unable to delete file "***.pchi".
>   Access to the path '***.pchi' is denied.

at the line#84 the .targets file has

> < Delete Condition="'%(ClCompile.DebugInformationFormat)' != '' and
>   '%(ClCompile.DebugInformationFormat)' != 'OldStyle' and
>   '%(ClCompile.ProgramDataBaseFileName)' != '' and
>   !Exists(%(ClCompile.ProgramDataBaseFileName))
>                and '%(ClCompile.UseMSVC)'!='true' and
>   '%(ClCompile.InterproceduralOptimization)'!='MultiFile' and
>   '%(ClCompile.LevelOfStaticAnalysis)'!='Brief' and 
>                '%(ClCompile.LevelOfStaticAnalysis)'!='Medium' and
>   '%(ClCompile.LevelOfStaticAnalysis)'!='Verbose'"
>               Files="%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile)i" />

Comment: <Delete Condition="'%(ClCompile.DebugInformationFormat)' != '' and '%(ClCompile.DebugInformationFormat)' != 'OldStyle' and '%(ClCompile.ProgramDataBaseFileName)' != '' and !Exists(%(ClCompile.ProgramDataBaseFileName))
             and '%(ClCompile.UseMSVC)'!='true' and '%(ClCompile.InterproceduralOptimization)'!='MultiFile' and '%(ClCompile.LevelOfStaticAnalysis)'!='Brief' and 
             '%(ClCompile.LevelOfStaticAnalysis)'!='Medium' and '%(ClCompile.LevelOfStaticAnalysis)'!='Verbose'"
            Files="%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile)i" />

Comment: [SOLVED] by copying the vc100.pdb from the Project1 as the Pre-Build event for Proj2.

Comment: For more information [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/645747/220636)